# Is it okay that there is no anchor peer on channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the [balance-transfer sample (typescript version)](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) among the official fabric samples, the client did not set any anchor peer over the channel. I checked that the `_anchor_peers` property of the `channel` object in the client was empty.

So, is it okay that there is no anchor peer on the channel? Or is the default anchor peer automatically set when we don't explicitly designate them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anchor peers enable cross organization communication for peers. There is no default anchor peer, you must explicitly declare one. Not having one on a channel will still allow peers of the same org be able to communicate.

Comment: Why is 'cross organization communication' needed? As far as I know, new blocks are delivered from the orderers and the leading peer disseminates blocks for other peers in the same organization. Is there any work to be done via cross organization communication?

Comment: Yes there is. It's called "SideDB" - where you only disclose data to a subset of the channel members, and the orderer doesn't have it.
On the public chain, only the hash of the data is present, and the data itself is replicated via gossip.
for more details: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1151

Comment: @yacovm Thanks for the explanation. Then, except for SideDB, which is still an experimental feature, does the cross organization communication not needed? At this moment, I don't consider the SideDB and I'm curious whether designating anchor peers is important.

Comment: It turns "non-experimental" (production) next month. Aside for that - it's not needed at the moment